# Add C++ function to different file and call it

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, if-statement, logic

I have cpp file f1.cpp, which looks like this

```
#include "header.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <vector>
#include "Pkins.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

size_t get_num_output_group(void) {
  return 4;
}

size_t get_num_feature(void) {
  return 44;
}

static inline size_t pred_form(float* pred) {
  const int num_class = 4;
  int max_index = 0;
  float max_margin = pred[0];
  int k;
  for (k = 1; k < num_class; ++k) {
    if (pred[k] > max_margin) {
      max_margin = pred[k];
      max_index = k;
    }
  }
  pred[0] = (float)max_index;
  return 1;
}

size_t predict_class(union Entry* data, int pred_margin, float* result) {
  float sum[4] = {0.0f};
  int i;
  unsigned int tmp;
  if (!(data[33].missing != -1) || (data[33].fvalue < 3.3902447)) {
    if (!(data[33].missing != -1) || (data[33].fvalue < 1.7016318)) {
      if (!(data[9].missing != -1) || (data[9].fvalue < 0.75673783)) {
        sum[0] += (float)-0.025704622;
      } else {
        sum[0] += (float)0.0013114753;
      }
    } else {
      if (!(data[6].missing != -1) || (data[6].fvalue < -5781.0889)) {
        if (!(data[34].missing != -1) || (data[34].fvalue < 2.2995086)) {
          sum[0] += (float)-0.02
         ...............
```

`predict_class` function is large, with 10k lines.

Currently I am calling it like this from the same file

```
  predict_class(data,0,result);
```

How do I add `predict_class` to other file and import it so that I can call it same way as I am doing currently.

Currently I have created `model.cpp` and added full content 10k lines of code into it.

And created header file `func.h`. How should I declare the function in this header file.

```
size_t predict_multiclass(union Entry* data, int pred_margin, float* result)
```

If I add this. much in header file, is it fine ?

Comment: You can declare the function in a header file, and include that in another .cpp file. See example here https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/header-files/

Comment: *function is large, with 10k lines* Unless the function is generated by some tool and never looked at by humans, this is a problem,

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem.: Yes it is model file convert to cpp program using some tool

Answer (score 2):

You should have a header file for `f1.cpp` first, that is `f1.hpp`.
In `f1.hpp`, declare the function you want to call in another file:

```
size_t predict_class(union Entry* data, int pred_margin, float* result);
```

Don't forget to include this header file in `f1.cpp`.
Then in the another file, include `f1.hpp` first, then you can call `predict_class`.

Comment: I want to just call the function `predict_class ` in f1.cpp, dont want to include 10k line of function in f1.cpp 
In this case where should I add the content of `predict_class ` function ?

Comment: @user3449212, there is a difference between `function definition` and `function declaration`. The body of the function goes into the `.cpp` file, the declaration (a.k.a. prototype) goes into the header file. It's not '10k line of function code', it's one line. You can, of course, just put the prototype in the file where you want to call it, but that's only if you are absolutely sure that the prototype will never change and/or will never be used anywhere else.

Comment: Okay, then you need to know which header file `predict_class` locates. Then include this header file in f1.cpp`. You don't need to add content again.

Comment: @RefugnicEternium: I understand. I have created `model.cpp` and added `predict_class ` function in it. And will declare this function  in `f1.h`. My only concern is  how do I declare the function in header file.  `size_t predict_multiclass(union Entry* data, int pred_margin, float* result)` is this correct way ?

Comment: Yes, @user3449212, that is the correct way. The prototype mirrors the header of the function 1:1. `ReturnType  FunctionName(Arguments);` <- Prototype, `ReturnType  FunctionName(Arguments) {}` <- Function Body.